# Псевдоним шаблона в самом шаблоне класса

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Рассмотрим класс итератора для массивов  `stdext::checked_array_iterator`, который определен в заголовочном файле `<iterator>`. Экземпляр класса можно использовать следующим образом:

```
char m[] = "2020 Happy New Year!";
constexpr size_t start = 5;
stdext::checked_array_iterator<const char*> It(m, strlen(m), start);
size_t count{}; //только для объяснений
while (true) {
    cout << *It++;
    ++count;
}
```

не беспокоясь о выходе за пределы массива (программа просто прекратится  как только выполнится `count + start  > strlen(m)`, а сообщение об ошибке получим в режиме отладки). Соответственно, класс имеет все необходимые стандартные определения для итератора. Там еще определен псевдоним типа:

```
template <class _Ptr>
class checked_array_iterator { // wrap a pointer with checking
    //...    
public:
     using _Prevent_inheriting_unwrap = checked_array_iterator;
     //...
}
```

Судя по названию, если пользоваться этим именем, то наследовать не получится(или я ошибаюсь?). Т.е попытка

```
using safe_ptr = typename 
stdext::checked_array_iterator<const char*>::_Prevent_inheriting_unwrap;
class D : public  safe_ptr   {//...};
```

будет неудачной. Но это не так.

**Вопрос:** для чего тогда определен псевдоним `_Prevent_inheriting_unwrap`?...